# Is there a difference between the two code codes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

First Code

```
console.log('Start');  // output 1
await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '<HTTP_URL>'
  data: <SOME_DATA>,
}).then ((response) => {
  // Do something... It could take a few seconds.
  console.log(response); // output 2
});
console.log('End');  // output 3
```

Second Code

```
console.log('Start');  // output 1
await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '<HTTP_URL>'
  data: <SOME_DATA>,
}).then (async (response) => {
  // Do something... It could take a few seconds.
  console.log(response); // output 2
});
console.log('End');  // output 3
```

Can the difference in asynchronous operation be caused by 'async' keyword of callback method?

In my test, the both source codes showed the same result.

In the second source code, I thought 'await' would guarantee only the call of the async callback.
However, it actually guaranteed the complete of the async callback.

Why if they do the same thing?

Comment: There is a difference, but I don't think it results in a perceived difference. I think they do the same thing

Comment: That `async` is unnecessary. You're not `await`ing anything in the callback and the return value of it will be a `Promise` either way.

Comment: @Andreas
Thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference would be if you need to await for a certain function within the `then` block.

```js
console.log('Start');  // output 1
await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '<HTTP_URL>'
  data: <SOME_DATA>,
}).then (async (response) => {
  // Do something... It could take a few seconds.
  await slowResponseFunction();
  console.log(response); // output 2
});
console.log('End');  // output 3
```

Comment: But since `slowResponseFunction` is inside a `then` you can just return it and put `console.log(response);` in a following `then`.

Comment: That's true. it could, but this syntax itself would have this difference. I guess mixing of `then` chaining and `async`/`await` makes it a bit convoluted.